# Textwidth not showing correctly in millimeters vb6

Tags: vb6

I have a picture box and I print contents in it. I want to know the exact textwidth of the text in millimeters. But I get wrong value. here is my code

```
me.scalemode = vbmillimeters
picturebox.scalemode = vbmillimeters

picturebox.fontname = "Arial"
picturebox.fontsize = 12
debug.print textwidth("AB.C.D.E. FGHIJKLMN")
```

When i measure in the printout in paper it is 48 mm
but it shows 32.97mm

please help me where am wrong.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

If you need the width of the text printed to the picture box, use:

`PictureBox.textwidth("AB.C.D.E. FGHIJKLMN")`

What you are actually doing: `textwidth("AB.C.D.E. FGHIJKLMN")` is mesuring the same text printed to the Form (`Me`).

Doing like this would be less error-prone:

```
Dim TextWidth as Single
With PictureBox
  .ScaleMode = vbMillimeters
  .FontName = "Arial"
  .FontSize = 12
  TextWidth = .TextWidth("AB.C.D.E. FGHIJKLMN")
End With
```

because if you are then switching to paper, you can also easily switch context:

```
With SelectedPrinter....
```

Comment: Of course it will fail at some High DPI settings.  VB6 uses something in OLE to perform those scalings, something that is off a bit at some DPI settings such as 200% (192 DPI).  7.5 twips/pixel gets truncated to 7 internally, throwing everything off.  Don't expect Microsoft to ever fix it though.  You won't see this unless your program is marked DPI-Aware anyway.